# Angular async pipe in *ngIf - handle 0 value

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I have the following html snippet:

```html
<div *ngIf="calculatedValue$ | async as calculatedValue">
  {{calculatedValue}}
</div>
```

But if the emitted value of calculatedValue$ is 0 (type = number), the div won't be displayed in the DOM.

What is the correct way to showing it?
Maybe in the way that a non null check gets added to the *ngIf.

Answer (score 5):

How mention @joosep parts in a comment, you can assign the value to an object, for example this code shows a progress bar even when its value is 0

**component.ts**

```
progress$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

**component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="{ value: progress$ | async } as progress">
    <app-progressBar
       [value]="progress.value"
    ></app-progressBar>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Awesome, this is a neat trick. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of *ngIf, just use *ngLet. There are multiple implementations of it on the web, for example within https://github.com/ngrx/component-builds.
I honestly don't understand why this is still not a part of angular core.

Answer (score 0):

As you already suggested; it's type need to be number.

`typeof (calculatedValue$ | async) === 'number'`

Or simply not null

`(calculatedValue$ | async) !== null`

Comment: But how it works with the assigment with 'as'? <div *ngIf="(calculatedValue$ | async !== null) as calculatedValue"> doesn't work

Comment: Please see my answer. https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-pipe-jghgvc?file=app%2Fasync-pipe%2Fasync-pipe.component.html

The easiest way to solve this issue is to turn the emitted value from the observable into an attribute on an object

Comment: @Joosep.P That breaks the ng-if, it will always show.

Comment: @user2622344 I have no idea, I would just avoid it.

Comment: @JoosepParts is the real answer, thank a lot!

Comment: better use "!= null" and "==null" which cover both undefined and null, which is what is usually intended by people (instead of "=== null" which is a bug 99% of the time)

Answer (score 0):

```
(calculatedValue$ | async) != null (and not !==)
(calculatedValue$ | async) == null (and not ===)
```

In my experience from reviewing lots of developer code, it's better to get used to always check against null by stating it explicitly, even if "it works" and unnecessary" in javascript. This will eliminate many future bugs like the 0 bug. I have seen lots and lots of bugs resulting from this.

You also want to get used to using the "== null" or "!= null" that covers both "null" and "undefined" unless you explicitly have a rare case where they are different.
This is true for all code in javascript/typescript.

Answer (score -1):

This is an expected behaviour. The following are all the values that javascript currently translates to false:

```
if (false)
if (null)
if (undefined)
if (0)
if (NaN)
if ('')
if ("")
if (``)
```

The easiest way to solve this issue is to turn the emitted value from the observable into an attribute on an object. You can do this in the component class file, or directly in the HTML. I’m going to do this directly in the HTML. Here’s what that looks like:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="{ observableValue: promise | async } as calculatedValue">
    <div *ngIf="calculatedValue.observableValue !== null">{{ calculatedValue.observableValue }} I am now showing</div>
</ng-container>
```

What we’ve done here is subscribed to the observable with the async pipe, and put the value into the observableValue attribute of an object. Notice the curly brackets inside the *ngIf structural directive. We then use the as syntax, which renames the variable for use in the template. Inside the double curly brackets, the result is output by accessing the observableValue attribute of the data object.
The *ngIf directive on the ng-container element will now always evaluate to true because we have created that object. So, no matter what value is emitted from the observable, we will output it to the screen.

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/async-pipe-jghgvc?file=app%2Fasync-pipe%2Fasync-pipe.component.html

Comment: Your ng-if will always evaluate to true, defeating its purpose.

Comment: You wanted `*ngIf` to show div when promise returns number 0. This is what happnes. 0 is emitted and div will show. When would you expect it to be falsy then?